# How do I access files during the packaging process that belong to a dependency of the current project that is being built?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

Scenario:
App needs dependency A.jar.

A.jar has a ProGuard obfuscation stage that generates a mapping file (A-mapping.txt).

App is getting obfuscation as well.

How do I pass A-mapping.txt to the app in its build process? I'd need something like a shared directory between all the dependencies where I put all my mapping files.

I want to include A-mapping.txt in app ProGuard configuration file with:
-applymapping A-mapping.txt

Would this be possible with Maven?

Comment: maven-remote-resources-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/)  might be a way... but I don't understand why you need that .txt file etc.

Comment: Because every dependency is creating its own mapping file and the maven module that pulls all of them together will need the mappings to translate from the dependencies classes original names to the obfuscated ones. Your suggestion is overkill, I was wondering if the modules could share files locally between themselves.

Comment: So do we have a multi module build?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `unpack` goal of the `maven-dependency` plugin .

Its documentation is here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html

For your case it should look like:

```xml
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.1</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>unpack</id>
             <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- change to best relevant phase -->
             <goals>
               <goal>unpack</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <artifactItems>
                 <artifactItem>
                   <groupId><!-- 'A' groupId--></groupId>
                   <artifactId>A</artifactId>
                   <version><!-- 'A' version--></version>
                   <type>jar</type>
                   <includes>/dir/inside/jar/to/A-mapping.txt</includes>
                 </artifactItem>
                 <!-- you may extract some more artifacts here -->
               </artifactItems>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/your/mappings</outputDirectory>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
```

You will have your mapping file extracted in `${project.build.directory}/your/mappings` so you can use them to build your final application in a subsequent maven phase.